# Simple linq question: How to filter a source afterwards?

Tags: linq

I have an 3-layered project, so that all Linq-Querys himself are in the DAL.
Now I have a filter function implemented in the Desig-Layer and want easily filter there, but how?

```
            Business.UserHandling uh = new Business.UserHandling();
            List<DAL.Benutzer> users = uh.GetUserOverview();
            gridUserOverview.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            gridUserOverview.DataSource = users;
            gridUserOverview.DataBind();
```

How can I user something like "users = users.Where("bla = 1")"?

---

I tried:

```
                Business.UserHandling uh = new Business.UserHandling();
            List<DAL.Benutzer> users = uh.GetUserOverview();

            var filters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            filters.Add(Request.QueryString["value"], Request.QueryString["text"]);
            users = users.Where(user => filters.All(filter => user.GetType().GetProperty(filter.Key).GetValue(user, null) == filter.Value)).ToList();

            gridUserOverview.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            gridUserOverview.DataSource = users;
            gridUserOverview.DataBind();
```

But it fails... I filtered on "UserID = 1", I have 2 Users, the filter should be filter 1 of these 2. But the return is 0 users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use a dynamic filter you can build a dictionary and verify the filter by reflection:

```
var filters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
filters.Add("bla", 1);
users.Where(user => filters.All(filter => user.GetType().GetProperty(filter.Key).GetValue(user, null) == filter.Value));
```

**Edit** Support all types convertible from string:

```
var users = new List<User>();
users.Add(new User {Age = 1 });
users.Add(new User { Age = 2 });
var filters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
filters.Add("Age", "1");
var filtered = users.Where(user => filters.All(filter =>
       {
           var propertyInfo = user.GetType().GetProperty(filter.Key);
           return Equals(propertyInfo.GetValue(user, null) , Convert.ChangeType(filter.Value, propertyInfo.PropertyType));
       }));

Assert.AreEqual(1, filtered.Count());
```

Comment: Nearly perfect, but I want to have a generic search, so I wand to enter the text "bla", beacuse it can be 10 different coloums, you know?!

Comment: In what form do you get the filter? As string with property name and value?

Comment: Correct, 2 strings with value and text

Comment: To get two strings, parameterName and parameterValue using LINQ, you might be stuck with a large switch statement or the joy that is reflection.

Comment: Added example in the middle, it works here.

Are you sure the values are OK (property name is case sensitive)

Comment: I'm sure, here my data:

http://localhost:60074/Admin/Users/Overview.aspx?value=BenutzerID&text=1

So, Key is "BenutzerID", text is "1".

Here I get it:

filters.Add(Request.QueryString["value"], Request.QueryString["text"]);

And here are my veriables of User: 

http://s2.imgimg.de/uploads/Capture6a469d22PNG.png

Comment: If user ID is int it must be parsed first...

int.Parse(Request.QueryString["text"])

Comment: That's not good, because I have different data types here to search for, who can I, without an endless switch, know if I must convert or not?
And I tried, it's not the reason!

Comment: Added example that supports multiple types

Answer (score 1):

You could change GetUserOverview to accept an expression, which would allow you to do custom filtering.

Example

```
public List<Benutzer> GetUserOverview(Func<Benutzer, bool> filter)
{
    //get your users however you were getting them
    var _result = new List<Benutzer>();

    _result = _result.Where(filter);
    return _result;
}
```

And that would let you do this:

```
List<DAL.Benutzer> users = uh.GetUserOverview(user => user.bla == 1);
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to dynamically build your filter you can do it this way:

```
Expression<Func<Benutzer, bool> finalFilter;

if (doFirstFilter)
{
    Expression<Func<Benutzer, bool> firstFilter = (user) => user.blah == 1;
}

if (doSecondFilter)
{
    Expression<Func<Benutzer, bool> secondFitler = 
        (user) => user.other == "whatever";
    finalFilter = Expression.Lambda<Func<Benutzer, bool>>(
        Expression.And(firstFilter, secondFilter));
}

var users = uh.GetUserOverview(finalFilter.Compile());
```

You can do all kinds of crazy stuff with Expressions.

Comment: Okay, that is nearly the same as Elisha postet, thank you.
But see the problem in his comment, how to solve?

Comment: Since you're filtering criteria is dynamic, you'll have to build it dynamically.  I'll update my answer with an example of how to do that.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not the count of filter that should be dynamic, it is the name of the to filter property.

Comment: @Kovu That's fine, using Expressions you can build all *kinds* of dynamic filters.  It's really just a matter of adapting the Expressions to meeting your business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this useful bit of code taken from [here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2007/06/15/9489.aspx)

```
public static IQueryable<T> AddEqualityCondition<T, V>(this IQueryable<T> queryable,string propertyName, V propertyValue)
        {
            ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
            IQueryable<T> x = queryable.Where<T>(
              Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(
                  pe,
                  typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName)),
                  Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(V)),
                  false,
                  typeof(T).GetMethod("op_Equality")),
              new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

            return (x);
        }
```